# Windows Phone - I want a `Grid` to do some animation when I tap on it

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, grid, expression-blend

I want a `Grid` to do some animation when I tap on it. That includes adding a tilt effect and chaning its Opacity. After you release your finger everything should go back to their original states.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course use `MouseLeftButtonUp` & `MouseLeftButtonDown' or 'ManipulationStarted` & `ManipulationCompleted` to handle the touch and release. But they are not always accurate.

Another solution is to use a `Button` as the host to encapsulate the animations you want within its visual state group.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="EmptyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.Projection>
                            <PlaneProjection/>
                        </Grid.Projection>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.4"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundVisual" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Root" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Root" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundVisual" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Opacity="0.4"/>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource EmptyButtonStyle}" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="360" Height="480"/>
</Grid>
```

In the `Button` style above, I have a `BackgroundVisual` (a `Rectangle`) as the background of the `Button` and set its initial `Opacity` to `0.2`. When pressed, I simply change the `Opacity` to `1`.

Also I gave the whole `Root` some `PlaneProjection` animations when pressed, just to create the tilt effect you need. Another way is to use the `Tilt` effect from the [WPToolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/), but that's assuming you are working on a WP8 project.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did it the same way. Added a button which removed almost all typical button properties (e.g. centered content, padding and margins) but had an animation to highlight a tap on the tile by moving it a few pixel to the top right.

Answer (score 1):

you can custom Grid VisualStateManager by Triggers to achieve.
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:ec="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
        xmlns:ic="clr- namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"

```
   <Grid x:name="main"> 
        <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager> 
            <ic:ExtendedVisualStateManager/> 
        </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager> 

 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                              <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                              <Storyboard>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="main">
                              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>0.5
                              </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                              </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              </Storyboard>
                              </VisualState>
                              <VisualState x:Name="UnSelected">
                              <Storyboard>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="main">
                              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                              <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                             1
                              </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                              </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              </Storyboard>
                              </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                              <ec:GoToStateAction StateName="Selected"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                              <ec:GoToStateAction StateName="UnSelected"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Grid>
  use the Tilt effect from the WPToolkit
```

Comment: +1, this could work, but as I stated in my answer, mouse events are not ideal for touch devices.